Aligning center of a short circular feature to a post's axis
Assume ASME Y17.5 standards:
Suppose I have a tall post and a short raised circle. I want the center point of the outer circle to be constrained to lie on the axis of the post. Is the below setup correct? It looks like a job for a position control, but I don't have basic dimensions to the position since they would be 0. In the absence of dimensions, is it interpreted as aligned with that datum?
And does it make sense to reference only one datum in the feature control box, or does datum B below need to be my primary (assuming I only care about the circle being on the axis regardless of how crooked the post is relative to B)?
Or maybe the approach should be completely different and I should be using runout?


The results depend a bit depending on what standard you invoke. Could you add this info to your post. I mean you would be fine if you use basic dimension while using ISO GD&T (so box around numeric value.

@joojaa Sorry, this is with the ASME standard. I edited the question to add that.
